# Python List to Dataframe conversion

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I have a list as below and I want to convert it into a dataframe:
[image]

but I am getting below error:
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(9, 5, 6)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Solution for this problem

Comment: post the actual list, not an image

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for `pd.concat`? ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html))

Can you specify what is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output : coef, std err, t etc will be column header(or key) and all the respective values will be list for each key